# How to Make a GlyphTypeface FontUri generic

Tags: c#, wpf, generics, fonts

We have the following image created in our code (It is used to make a image that says "File" for use in the Ribbon):

```
 <DrawingImage x:Key="FileText">
    <DrawingImage.Drawing>
        <GlyphRunDrawing ForegroundBrush="White">
            <GlyphRunDrawing.GlyphRun>
                <GlyphRun
                        CaretStops="{x:Null}" 
                        ClusterMap="{x:Null}" 
                        IsSideways="False" 
                        GlyphOffsets="{x:Null}" 
                        GlyphIndices="41 76 79 72" 
                        FontRenderingEmSize="12" 
                        DeviceFontName="{x:Null}" 
                        AdvanceWidths="5.859375 2.90625 2.90625 6.275390625">
                    <GlyphRun.GlyphTypeface>
                        <GlyphTypeface FontUri="C:\WINDOWS\Fonts\SEGOEUI.TTF"/>
                    </GlyphRun.GlyphTypeface>
                </GlyphRun>
            </GlyphRunDrawing.GlyphRun>
        </GlyphRunDrawing>
    </DrawingImage.Drawing>
</DrawingImage>
```

The problem is that one of our customers has a Windows image that does not use C:\Windows rather they use C:\WINNT. This will cause the application to crash at startup with a not very helpful log. Any ideas how to generalize the FontUri so that it will work on system setups like this as well?

Comment: Can you use `%systemroot%` instead of `C:\Windows` in your path?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have a few options. The first would be to embed any fonts used. This may cause you to run into licensing problems, but would obviate specifying absolute paths.

The second option would be to utilize a markup extension:

```
// nb: there is a bug in the VS designer which requires this type of extension
// be used as an element if you embed another markup extension in it.
public class FindFirstFileExtension : MarkupExtension
{
    public Environment.SpecialFolder Root { get; set; }
    public string Paths { get; set; }

    public override object ProvideValue(IServiceProvider serviceProvider)
    {
        if (String.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(this.Paths)) return null;

        var root = Environment.GetFolderPath(this.Root);
        var uri = this.Paths
                      .Split(',')
                      .Select(p => Path.Combine(root, p))
                      .FirstOrDefault(p => File.Exists(p));

        return uri != null ? new Uri(uri) : null;
    }
}
```

This would then allow you to provide a comma separated list of fonts to use, relative to `SpecialFolder.Fonts` (which should "solve" that problem of differing folder names):

```
<GlyphRun.GlyphTypeface>
     <GlyphTypeface
         FontUri="{local:FindFirstFile Paths='SEGOEUI.TTF,ARIAL.TTF,TIMES.TTF', Root=Fonts}" />
</GlyphRun.GlyphTypeface>
```

Answer (score 2):

I was thinking of the same thing as Rachel, why can't you use an environment variable? You could indeed do, when you derive from GlyphTypeface:

```
public class MyGlyphTypeface : GlyphTypeface
{
    private string fontPath;

    public string FontPath
    {
        get { return fontPath; }
        set
        {
            fontPath = value;
            FontUri = new Uri(Environment.ExpandEnvironmentVariables(fontPath));
        }
    }
}
```

and use it like this:

```
<GlyphRun.GlyphTypeface>
    <local:MyGlyphTypeface FontPath="%SystemRoot%\Fonts\SEGOEUI.TTF"/>
</GlyphRun.GlyphTypeface>
```

Comment: You could avoid using an environment variable all together (environment variables are bad...) by using `Environment.GetFolderPath(Environment.SpecialFolder.Fonts)`.

Comment: @sixlettervariables Yes, but then you loose some flexibility of specifying the path in XAML.